# python class question does not give output also error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, type):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.type = type
        self.gas_tank_size = 14
        self.fuel_level = 0

    def fuel_up(self):
        self.fuel_level = self.gas_tank_size
        print('Gas tank is now full.')

    def drive(self):
        print(f'The {self.model} is now driving.')
```

I am a beginner for python class structure so it does not give error but it gives nothing. Could you explain please where is the mistake or what is the problem?

Comment: You didn't _tell_ it to output anything. This code never creates an instance of this class

Comment: What are you expecting as output? @Melisahan. Also you should not be using in-built keywords as variable names (Here `type`)

Comment: You just defined a class, you never actually execute anything so there is nothing to output.

Answer (score 2):

Simply declaring a class does not make anything happen - you have to actually invoke that code outside of the class.

For example, try adding this code below the class, with no indentation (so that python doesn't consider it to be part of the class):

```
# create an instance of the Vehicle class, and assign it to a variable called 'v'
v = Vehicle("someBrand", "someModel", "someType")
# call the fuel_up() and drive() methods, which should print to the console
v.fuel_up()
v.drive()
```

Comment: You might wanna add what construction does @Green

Answer (score 0):

A class will not output anything by itself. When make a class object, for example by `v = Vehicle(brand, model, type)`, it will run the `__init__` function. This function does not return anything in your code.
If you want it to output anything from any of the other functions of the class, you should continue with something like

```
v = Vehicle(brand, model, type)
v.fuel_up()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will just create a class and function. It won't do anything until you initialize the class

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, type):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.type = type
        self.gas_tank_size = 14
        self.fuel_level = 0

    def fuel_up(self):
        self.fuel_level = self.gas_tank_size
        print('Gas tank is now full.')

    def drive(self):
        print(f'The {self.model} is now driving.')


#Initializing the class
vehicle = Vehicle(brand="Mercedes-Benz", model="A-Class", type="Automatic")
vehicle.fuel_up()
vehicle.drive()
```

Output:

```
Gas tank is now full.
The A-Class is now driving.
```